# How can I fix a pixeled-aliased font when I run a tkinter code from a terminal

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm working with a python-tkinter code and I have different results if I run it from a terminal (`$ python3 file.py`) and if I make a laucher to run it with the next instruction: xterm -e "python3 file.py".

This is the code in 'file.py':

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

color = 'goldenrod4' 
root.geometry("1350x750+0+0")
root.title("Carabina 30-30")
root.configure(background=color)

Top = Frame(root, width=1350, height=100, bd=14)
Top.pack(side=TOP, fill = X)
Top.configure(background=color)

Tops = Frame(Top, width = 100, height = 100, bd = 14)
Tops.configure(background='red')
Tops.pack(side=RIGHT)
Tops.configure(background=color)


lblInfo = Label(Top, font=('Arial', 40, 'bold'), text = "Carabina 30-30", bd=15, background='black', fg = 'white')
lblInfo.config(activebackground = 'red')
lblInfo.pack(side=LEFT)



root.mainloop()
```

When I do the first, the result is not smooth:
[bad result, aliased font](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4yh26tjm150lww8/resultado1.png?dl=0)

If I do the second, the result is:
[good result, antialiased, smooth](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2z26v03rfmi9ryk/resultado2.png?dl=0)

Obviously, I want the second result in any of the ways.
In fact, if I enter the same line as in the launcher, but in the terminal, i have the same bad first result.

How can I reach the correct smooth font in every situation? What is wrong with the first way?

Thank you!

More (and new) information:
I installed python3-tk using "apt-get install", but python3 was installed with anaconda3. Maybe it's important because when I wrote `$ conda init bash` in a terminal, and then closed and opened it, the bash line had `(base)` in its beginning. Then I wrote `$ conda deactivate`, tried to run the program 'file.py' using `$ python3 file.py` and *voilá*... I had the result I wished.
I really don't know what is happening, but that worked. I'll appreciate any information.

Thanks!

Comment: maybe conda sets some settings in environment and don't remove them after deactivation. You can check `$ env` before and after using conda.

Comment: on images it looks like bad result couldn't find Arial and use some default font.